# Create comma separated list of links with variable in PHP

Tags: php, list, hyperlink

I have a variable which renders a list of usernames. Now, I need to add a link to each username. The link is built from a fixed URL and the username as a variable.

Example link: 
https://www.example.org/something?userid=$username

```
$usernames = $_POST['username'];
$username = '';
foreach($usernames as $value) {
$username .= "'" . $value . "', ";
}
$username = rtrim($username, ', ');
```

And then, I have the construction of the list:

```
<?php  $urls = explode(',', $usernameid);
$nritems = count ($urls); 
$positem = 0;
foreach($urls as $key => $usernameid)
{
echo "<a href="https://www.example.org/something?userid=' . $usernameid . 
'">'. $usernameid . '</a>";
if (++$positem != $nritems) { echo ", ";}
}?>
```

The variable is also used in other parts of the code, so I can't change it. The list is not displaying now.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: the form:

```
<form action="list.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <div id="usrselect">
    <label>Select user <input type="text" name="username[]" id="userid" class="typeahead" required/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="button-section"> <input type="submit" name="List" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: A little help `https://www.example.org/something?userid=1` will produce
`$_POST['userid']`, where `$_POST['userid']` will equal `1`. $_POST['username'] won't even exist. Also `$_POST['userid']` won't be an array, and you can't use it in `foreach`. it will yeald warnings.

Comment: $POST is used to 'catch' the username from an input field in a form. Used as is in the code it does work as expected. It returns the username or list of usernames (if more are selected in the form). What I can't get around is creating links for each username in that list.

Comment: Watch your quotes in that `echo` line, `"<a href="` won't work, as well as `. '</a>";`

Comment: @SCor, Well the part of the code with the form is missing. So I based my assumption on the existing code. Also adding to the quotes part - where exactly are you getting `$usernameid`? As far as i see it is undefined.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin: you're right. Here's the missing part (the form)><form action="list.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div id="usrselect">
<label>Select user <input type="text" name="username[]" id="userid" class="typeahead" required/></label>
</div>
<div class="button-section">
     <input type="submit" name="List" />
     </div>
</form>

Comment: @kerbholz: that's what I think I need help with.. the quotes. Tried multiple versions. None worked so far. This version:

Comment: This version:<?php  $urls = explode(',', $usernameid);
$nritems = count ($urls); 
$positem = 0;
foreach($urls as $key => $usernameid)
{
echo "<a href='https://www.example.org/something?userid=' . $usernameid . 
''>'. $usernameid . '</a>";
if (++$positem != $nritems) { echo ", ";}
}?> 
will result in the variable not being passed into the link. And the link text is the actual variable, with quotations and dots.

Comment: @SCor, make sure `$urls` actually contains something, `print_r($urls)` right after `$urls = explode(',', $usernameid);`. Speaking of, where is `$usernameid` in that line coming from? You defined `$username` before, but not `$usernameid`, did you mean to `$urls = explode(',', $username);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution, for those who might face the same problem:

```
<?php $urls = explode(',', $usernameid);
$nritems = count ($urls); 
$positem = 0;
$displayuser = array("'", " ");
foreach($urls as $key => $usernameid)
{
echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/something?userId='.str_replace($displayuser, "", $usernameid).'">'.str_replace($displayuser, "", $usernameid).'</a>';
if (++$positem != $nritems) { echo ", ";}
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get your quotes right:

```
echo '<a href="https://www.example.org/something?userid='.$usernameid.'">'.$usernameid.'</a>';
```

or

```
echo "<a href=\"https://www.example.org/something?userid={$usernameid}\">{$usernameid}</a>";
```

or

```
echo sprintf('<a href="https://www.example.org/something?userid=%d">%d</a>', $usernameid, $usernameid);
```

Comment: None of these is working, sadly. And in the last version, there's a quotation mark that needs to be changed. The " after </a>, should be '

Comment: These are valid examples and produce correct code, if something "isn't working", it has to do with `$usernameid`. I fixed the `'`, thanks.

Comment: the variable actually contains the correct $usernameid (instead of $username)

Comment: So what exactly isn't working then? Wrong url? Wrong id? Do you get any errors in your log files or on screen? Does this code produce the correct code to link or is the error somewhere else in your code?